# How to handle animation state change for a collection of attacks(instances of a class)?[2D]

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an Animation controller that plays animations(2d with no exit time) when the proper state is triggered. This is usually done through a bool like "isJumping" or "isDucking" from the behaviors themselves. 
I've done it this way so that the behaviors aren't coupled to the animation state. The Animation Controller knows about the behaviors.

I have an "Attack" behavior that holds data about it such as damage, speed, delay. I have an "AttackCombo" Script that holds an array of "Attack" behaviors. On input it will execute the attack logic and iterate to the next Attack within the array. This allows me to customize an attack and put it into a combo, however with this method I can't use a bool like "IsAttacking" as the behavior has multiple instances unlike jump or duck. I don't want to have to make an individual class for each attack in a combo, i'm sure there's a better more modular way to handle my problem.

I'm open to better ways to handle animation in general, i've done research and can't find much regarding best practices with 2d transitions for Unity.

```
public class AnimationManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;
    private InputState inputState;
    private ColisionState colisionState;
    private Walk walkBehavior;
    private Duck duckBehavior;

    private void Awake()
    {
        inputState = GetComponent<InputState>();
        colisionState = GetComponent<ColisionState>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        walkBehavior = GetComponent<Walk>();
        duckBehavior= GetComponent<Duck>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (colisionState.isStanding)
        {
            ChangeAnimationState(0);
        }

        if (inputState.absVelX > 0)
        {
            ChangeAnimationState(1);
        }

        if (inputState.absVelY > 0)
        {
            ChangeAnimationState(2);
        }


        if (duckBehavior.isDucking)
        {
            ChangeAnimationState(3);
        }
    }


        private void ChangeAnimationState(int value)
        {
            animator.SetInteger("AnimState", value);
        }
    }


 public class AttackCombo : MonoBehaviour
        {
            public Attack[] Attacks;
            public int CurrentIndex;


        private void Update()
        {
            if (CanAttack)

                Attacks[CurrentIndex].OnAttack();

               // Normally this would let the Animation Controller to play 
the animation but since there are multiple states depending on the index 
this method won't work. 
                Attacks[CurrentIndex].isAttacking = true;
                CurrentIndex++;
            }
    }
```

Comment: You can define an int parameter in the animator and give each state a value.

Comment: You can try a blend tree for your attack.